# Creating an RMI Connector Client

Tags: java, jboss, rmi, mbeans

I am trying to connect to MBean server. I need to write JMX Client application. This is the code used for client application. But I have got an exception related to this

> Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub:
>   javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException [Root exception is
>   java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: localhost;
>   nested exception is:

Can somebody help me to fix this.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.management.MBeanServerConnection;
import javax.management.MBeanServerInvocationHandler;
import javax.management.MalformedObjectNameException;
import javax.management.ObjectName;
import javax.management.remote.JMXConnector;
import javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory;
import javax.management.remote.JMXServiceURL;


public class SystemConfigClient {

    public static final String HOST = "localhost";
    public static final String PORT = "1099";


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, MalformedObjectNameException {
        JMXServiceURL url =new JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://" + HOST + ":" +PORT+ "/jmxrmi");

        JMXConnector jmxConnector = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(url);
        MBeanServerConnection mbeanServerConnection = jmxConnector.getMBeanServerConnection();
        //ObjectName should be same as your MBean name
        ObjectName mbeanName = new ObjectName("ifs.demo1.jmx:type=SystemConfig");

        //Get MBean proxy instance that will be used to make calls to registered MBean
        SystemConfigMBean mbeanProxy =
            (SystemConfigMBean) MBeanServerInvocationHandler.newProxyInstance(
                mbeanServerConnection, mbeanName, SystemConfigMBean.class, true);

        //let's make some calls to mbean through proxy and see the results.
        System.out.println("Current SystemConfig::" + mbeanProxy.doConfig());

        mbeanProxy.setSchemaName("NewSchema");
        mbeanProxy.setThreadCount(5);

        System.out.println("New SystemConfig::" + mbeanProxy.doConfig());

        //let's terminate the mbean by making thread count as 0
        mbeanProxy.setThreadCount(0);

        //close the connection
        jmxConnector.close();
    }

}
```

I have run this code with following arguments.

> Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099
>   Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
>   Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false

but I got the exception of

> Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Failed to retrieve
>   RMIServer stub: javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException [Root
>   exception is java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host:
>   localhost; nested exception is:   java.net.ConnectException:
>   Connection refused: connect]  at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.connect(RMIConnector.java:338)
>     at
>   javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.connect(JMXConnectorFactory.java:248)
>     at
>   javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.connect(JMXConnectorFactory.java:207)
>     at com.demo1.jmx.SystemConfigClient.main(SystemConfigClient.java:29)
>   Caused by: javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException [Root exception is
>   java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: localhost;
>   nested exception is:      java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused:
>   connect]  at
>   com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContext.lookup(RegistryContext.java:101)
>     at
>   com.sun.jndi.toolkit.url.GenericURLContext.lookup(GenericURLContext.java:185)
>     at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)  at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.findRMIServerJNDI(RMIConnector.java:1886)
>     at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.findRMIServer(RMIConnector.java:1856)
>     at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.connect(RMIConnector.java:257)
>     ... 3 more Caused by: java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused
>   to host: localhost; nested exception is:      java.net.ConnectException:
>   Connection refused: connect   at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:601)     at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:198)
>     at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:184)
>     at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:322)   at
>   sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)     at
>   com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContext.lookup(RegistryContext.java:97)
>     ... 8 more Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused:
>   connect   at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:333)  at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
>     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:182)   at
>   java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)    at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)  at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)  at
>   java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:375)   at
>   java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:189)   at
>   sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:22)
>     at
>   sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:128)
>     at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:595)
>     ... 13 more Java Result: 1

Answer (score 2):

Have you noticed that you are using the VM arguments with "D" and not "-D"? Or is it just a typo? 
The correct would be:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

Comment: Hi, what do you think about https://stackoverflow.com/q/59471539/1410223